# Hamming Bound-like upper bounds on q-element codes when the minimum distance is even

Tags: combinatorics, coding-theory

If there exists a q-tuple code (n, K, d) where $d = 2l$ is even, prove that

$q^n\ge K(q-1)\sum_{i=0}^{l-1}\binom{n}{i}(q-1)^i$

My thought was to take into account the number of vectors with distance $n$ from the code word, but that would be duplicative. Besides that, formally I don't know how this coefficient $(q-1)$ should be constructed

This question arises after the textbook proofs of Hamming Bound and Singleton Bound; perhaps the idea of a proof of Singleton Bound would be helpful for that question?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: This bound also shows that when $d$ is even, the code cannot be a perfect code